Create Two Spotlights using box-shadow property
I'm trying to create a guide that have two spotlights simultaneously. When I trying to add another spotlight, both the spotlight area looks shadowy. How to avoid the shadows of one spotlight area to overlap with other spotlight areas? The box-shadow is to spotlight the desired area while making the other parts of the page looks like there is an overlay above it.
This is the link to fiddle to try out. https://jsfiddle.net/ad1xzbwy/

Here is how it looks like when there is only one spotlight.

Here is how it looks like when there is two spotlights.
This is the code for the simple example.


function scrollToArticle(articleId) {
  const articleElement = document.getElementById(articleId);
  if (articleElement) {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: articleElement.offsetTop,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }
}

// Check if it's the user's first visit and apply the spotlight effect if it is
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('hasVisited')) {
    document.body.classList.add('spotlight-active');
    localStorage.setItem('hasVisited', 'true');
  }
  
  //for testing use
  document.body.classList.add('spotlight-active');
  
});

// Optional: Close the spotlight effect on click or after a certain time
document.querySelector('.overlay').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.remove('spotlight-active');
  hideSpotlight();
});

function hideSpotlight() {
  // Hide overlay，spotlight， message box and arrow guide
  var overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
  var spotlight = document.querySelector('.spotlight');
  var spotlight2 = document.querySelector('.spotlight-2');
  var messageZone = document.querySelector('.message-zone');
  var arrowGuide = document.querySelector('.arrow-guide');
  overlay.style.display = 'none';
  spotlight.style.display = 'none';
  spotlight2.style.display = 'none';
  messageZone.style.display = 'none';
  arrowGuide.style.display = 'none';
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  showArticleSwitchWidget();
});

function showArticleSwitchWidget() {
  //$(".switch-article-overlay .overlay-label").addClass('hidden');
  $(".switch-article-overlay .overlay-icon svg path").attr( "d", "M8.59 16.59L13.17 12 8.59 7.41 10 6l6 6-6 6-1.41-1.41z");
}
function hideArticleSwitchWidget() {
  $(".switch-article-overlay .overlay-icon svg path").attr("d","M15.41 16.59L10.83 12l4.58-4.59L14 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41z");
}
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.article {
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.vertical-timeline {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #CC0E19;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 80px;
z-index: 100;
}
.label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.label-pentagon {
  background-color: #CC0E19;
  width: 105px;
  height: 30px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 30px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 30px) 100%, 0 100%);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding-left:5px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
.label-triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #CC0E19;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}
.triangle-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 20px;
  color: #CC0E19;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 20px;
}

.spotlight-active .overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*background: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.7);*/
  z-index: 50; /* Above the content but below the labels */
  display: block; /* Show the overlay */
}
.spotlight-active .spotlight.desktop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 35px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 51; /* Above the overlay */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* Large shadow with a "cut-out" effect */
  display: block; /* Show the spotlight */
  background-clip: content-box; /* Ensures the inner background is clipped to the content box */
}

.spotlight-active .spotlight-2.desktop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 350px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 51; /* Above the overlay */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* Large shadow with a "cut-out" effect */
  display: block; /* Show the spotlight */
  background-clip: content-box; /* Ensures the inner background is clipped to the content box */
}

.message-zone {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  left: 320px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 52;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 220px;
}
.message-box {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 52;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 220px;
}
.ok-button {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: #CC0E19;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}  
.arrow-guide {
  position: fixed;
  top: 130px;
  left: 140px;
  z-index: 102;
}

.spotlight-active .spotlight.mobile {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: -20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 51;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: block;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
.message-zone.mobile {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  left: 320px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 52;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 220px;
}
.arrow-guide.mobile {
  position: fixed;
  top: 130px;
  left: 140px;
  z-index: 102;
}


.switch-article-overlay {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 110px;
  z-index:99999;
}
.switch-article-overlay button.overlay-icon {
  background-color: #CC0E19;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
  height: 30px;
  max-width: none;
  width: 0.3em;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.1em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.1em;
  border: 1px solid #636363;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;    
}
button.overlay-icon {
  background: 0 0;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: visible;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.switch-article-overlay button.overlay-icon svg {
  fill: #fff;
}
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="spotlight desktop"></div>
<div class="spotlight-2 desktop"></div>

<div class="vertical-timeline mobile-hidden">
  <div class="label" style="top:0px;" onclick="scrollToArticle('article1')">
    <div class="label-pentagon">Main News</div>
  </div>
  <div class="label" style="top:30px;" onclick="scrollToArticle('article2')">
    <div class="label-triangle"></div>
    <div class="triangle-text">Second News</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="message-zone">
    <div class="message-box">
      <div class="message-content">Click to read the next news</div>
    </div>
  <button class="ok-button" onclick="hideSpotlight()">OK</button>
</div>

<img class="arrow-guide" src="arrow-left-white.png"/>

<div class="switch-article-overlay">
  <button class="overlay-icon" title="article switching">  
    <!--
    right arrow
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"></path>
      <path d="M15.41 16.59L10.83 12l4.58-4.59L14 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41z"></path>
    </svg>
    -->    
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"></path>
      <path d="M8.59 7.41L13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6-6-6-1.41 1.41z"></path>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>

<div id="article1" class="article">
  <h2>Article 1</h2>
</div>

<div id="article2" class="article">
  <h2>Article 2</h2>
</div>



Have tried searching for answer, but didn't found one. Try the best to maintain the box-shadow property.

Not really using box-shadow, but I believe you can get pretty much the same result using the below technique:


.page  {
  display: grid;
  gap: 6px;
}
.page div {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.spots {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: silver;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}
.spots div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
}

#spot1 {
  left: 60px;
  top: 20px;
}
#spot2 {
  left: 150px;
  top: 50px;
}
<div class="page">
  <div>line 1</div>
  <div>line 1</div>
  <div>line 1</div>
  <div>line 1</div>
  <div>line 1</div>
  <div>line 1</div>
  <div>line 1</div>
</div>

<div class="spots">
  <div id="spot1"></div>
  <div id="spot2"></div>
</div>



